# Deprecation warning about boolean casting for *args

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In upgrading from Rails 4.1.9 to 4.2.0, I received the deprecation warning `` You attempted to assign a value which is not explicitly `true` or `false` to a boolean column... `` for the following code in my spec_helper file:

```
def Factory(*args)
     FactoryGirl.create *args
end
```

The warning typically occurs when I call one of my factories:

```
Factory(:invitation)
```

Why do I get this warning when I am not setting a boolean and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was not explicitly setting a boolean with this call, I was implicitly setting one. The invocation of

```
Factory(:invitation)
```

calls the factory definition in the `factories.rb` file. The definition of the Invitation factory does set a boolean field of Invitation.  Furthermore it turns out I had a typo and was setting the boolean field to :false rather than false, i.e. to a symbol rather than to a valid boolean value.  Accordingly, the deprecation warning allowed me to find a potential bug.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4.2 a new (better) implementation of Type Casting is introduced:

http://technology.customink.com/blog/2015/01/06/activerecord-42s-type-casting/

This now warns about incorrect type that is set for the boolean.

In our case, upon migrating to Rails 4.2 this stopped giving us an exception that we had programmed in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean`

The solution I implemented was adding this `active_record_monkey_patch.rb` in the config/initializers directory:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Type
    class Boolean < Value

      private

      def cast_value(value)
        if value == ''
          nil
        elsif ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES.include?(value)
          true
        elsif ConnectionAdapters::Column::FALSE_VALUES.include?(value)
          false
        else
          raise InputDataError, 'Invalid boolean (use false or true for boolean).'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  module ConnectionAdapters
    class Column
      TRUE_VALUES << 'j' << 'J' << 'True' << 'y' <<'Y'

      FALSE_VALUES << 'n' << 'N' << 'False'
    end
  end
end
```